# Remote access to web server on linux

Tags: linux, apache, ssh, server, centos

I have access to a server running CentOS 6.7 on which I installed apache and configured the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file.
I can see the webpage if I ssh to the server and run

```
$ lynx http://192.99.x.x
```

but I would like to access it using a real browser. If I try to access it from my computer, it tells me that this webpage is unavailable and if I try to run firefox on the CentOS terminal, I get error: No Display specified.

Is there a way to see the webpage in a browser without port forwarding ?

Comment: Properly config ips on the server, you should be able to see it feom outside if visible from inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without port forwarding, you will need to setup X11 forwarding in SSH. This will allow you to open graphical applications remotely. Below is a link to configure X11 forwarding for SSH.

[X11 Forwarding with SSH](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Displaying_CentOS_6_Applications_Remotely_%28X11_Forwarding%29)

[CentOS 6 SSH Configuration](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_CentOS_6_Remote_Access_using_SSH)